# Karma Disconnected automatically (because no message in 10000 ms.)

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, tdd, karma-runner

I am new in unit testing using angularJs with karma and jasmine. I have a problem while executing test cases.

```
 I got 22 12 2016 11:48:25.207:WARN [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0)]: Disconnected (
1 times), because no message in 10000 ms.
```

I searched on google and I add `browserNoActivityTimeout: 60000,` in my configuration file. After that I got the following error:

```
Missing error handler on `socket`.
TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:7:11)
    at Object.dirname (path.js:695:5)
    at JenkinsReporter.specSuccess.specSkipped.specFailure (C:\Users\manpreet.ka
ur\Desktop\content\node_modules\karma-jenkins-reporter\index.js:97:31)
    at JenkinsReporter.BaseReporter.onSpecComplete (C:\Users\manpreet.kaur\Deskt
op\content\node_modules\karma\lib\reporters\base.js:78:12)
    at Server.<anonymous> (C:\Users\manpreet.kaur\Desktop\content\node_modules\k
arma\lib\events.js:13:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:111:20)
    at Server.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Browser.onResult (C:\Users\manpreet.kaur\Desktop\content\node_modules\kar
```

Here is the version of nodejs and karma:

```
node: v6.9.1
Karma version: 0.13.22
```

These test cases are working fine in other systems. I am using windows8.

Comment: Are you using asynchronous code in the test? You might need to use done().

Comment: can you show your failing tests, and list your jasmine version?